# How To Separate String using SPLIT

Tags: c#

```
string str = "1 JPY = 1.3893 USD";
```

That is my output of a code. I only want to get value (1.3893) and assign it to a variable.

Is it possible to do so using split?

Comment: `var result =  str.Split('=').Last().Trim();` Read the documentation of Split.

Answer (score 1):

See the below code sample.

```
string str = "1 JPY = 1.3893";
string[] words = str.Split(' ');
int i=0;
foreach (string word in words)
{
    i++;
    if(word == "=")
    break;

}
string value= words[i];
```

Comment: Can u check my code again, i want the middle value, ur code works fine for the last one. my output would be "USD", but i want the int value

Comment: it wont return any value :(

Answer (score 0):

Giving for granted your output will always have the same format:

```
string str = "1 JPY = 1.3893 USD";
var split = str.Split(' ')[3];
Console.WriteLine(split);
```

Comment: Can u check my code again, i want the middle value, ur code works fine for the last one. my output would be "USD", but i want the int value

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to split using the space and take always the 4th value of the array... But again, this will work only if your output is always the same: var split = str.Split(' ')[3].Trim();

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` will let you split the string into an array. The following example splits it, using the spaces in the string as the delimiter.

Your string would be turned into a string array as the return value from calling `Split`.

- [0] = 1
- [1] = JPY
- [2] = =
- [3] = 1.3893
- [4] = USD

Calling `str.Split` will let you access the value stored in index 3, which is the number you are after.

```
string str = "1 JPY = 1.3893 USD";
string val = str.Split(' ')[3];
```

Comment: Putting [3] returns "=".

Comment: I tired putting [4], it returns nothing